# Git repo server claims git is not installed

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a gitlab install via the omnibus package. When I log in 
on my own account, and run

`git --version`

the shell claims that git is not installed.  My guess is that git is simply not on my path. What is the best way of finding the correct path to the git binary?

Comment: If `which git` comes up empty, you probably don't have Git installed.

Comment: Thanks, Makoto. This is strange, because this is a working git repo server. But yes, `which git` comes up empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The omnibus has git placed in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin`